# Customers with purchases on consecutive days

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Below is my attempt to try and list customers who have made purchases for 10 or more consecutive days.

I'm trying to get the output (see below) and could use some help. I know this could probably be done with MATCH_RECOGNIZE but I'm not that familiar with it so I would prefer enhancing my current attempt or certainty open to any other suggestions that will achieve my desired output.

Below is my test CASE. Thanks in advance to all who answer.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE customers 
(CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) AS
SELECT 1, 'Faith', 'Mazzarone' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lisa', 'Saladino' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Micheal', 'Palmice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Joseph', 'Zaza' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Jerry', 'Torchiano' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);

CREATE TABLE items 
(PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE) AS
SELECT 100, 'Black Shoes', 79.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Brown Pants', 111.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 'White Shirt', 10.99 FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE items 
ADD CONSTRAINT items_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id);

create table purchases(
  ORDER_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
  customer_id   number, 
  PRODUCT_ID NUMBER, 
  QUANTITY NUMBER, 
  purchase_date timestamp
);

ALTER TABLE purchases 
ADD CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_id);

ALTER TABLE purchases ADD CONSTRAINT customers_fk FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id);

ALTER TABLE purchases ADD CONSTRAINT items_fk FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES items(product_id);

insert  into purchases (customer_id, product_id, quantity, purchase_date) 
SELECT 3, 102, 4,TIMESTAMP '2022-12-22 21:44:35' + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY') FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 15 UNION ALL 
select 1, 101,3, date '2023-03-29' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 12
union all
select 2, 101,2, date '2023-01-15' + level * interval '8' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 2, 102,2,date '2023-04-13' + level * interval '1 1' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 11
union all
select 3, 101,2, date '2023-02-01' + level * interval '1 05:03' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 10
union all
select 3, 101,1, date '2023-04-22' + level * interval '23' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 23
union all
select 3, 100,1,  date '2022-03-01' + level * interval '1 00:23:05' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 4, 102,1, date '2023-01-01' + level * interval '5' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 60;

WITH t as (
     select distinct CUSTOMER_ID,
    trunc(PURCHASE_DATE) dat
       from purchases
    )
    ,tt as (
        select t.*
        ,row_number() over (partition by CUSTOMER_ID order by dat) rn
        from t
    )
   ,ttt as (
   select CUSTOMER_ID, 
         min(dat) start_date,
         max(dat) end_date,
         count(*) day_count
     from tt
     group by 
      CUSTOMER_ID, dat-rn
      having count(*) >= 10
   )
   select 
           c.customer_id,
           c.first_name,
           c.last_name,  
           ttt.start_date,
           ttt.end_date,
           ttt.day_count
     from   customers c, ttt
    where  
    c.customer_id = ttt.customer_id;

/*desired output */

CUSTOMER_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   FIRST_DATE  LAST_DATE   DAY_COUNT   PURCHASE_COUNT
2   Lisa    Saladino    14-APR-2023 00:00:00    24-APR-2023 00:00:00    11  11
3   Micheal Palmice 02-MAR-2022 00:00:00    16-MAR-2022 00:00:00    15  15
3   Micheal Palmice 22-APR-2023 00:00:00    14-MAY-2023 00:00:00    23  23
4   Joseph  Zaza    01-JAN-2023 00:00:00    13-JAN-2023 00:00:00    13  60
```

Comment: Quite an interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would prefer enhancing my current attempt

You could get the result you want by changing the first CTE 't' query:

```
     select distinct CUSTOMER_ID,
    trunc(PURCHASE_DATE) dat
       from purchases
```

to

```
     select CUSTOMER_ID,
    trunc(PURCHASE_DATE) dat,
    count(*) cnt
       from purchases
   group by CUSTOMER_ID, trunc(PURCHASE_DATE)
```

and then including that in the 'ttt' query:

```
         sum(cnt) purchase_count
```

and final select list. Altogether (and without fixing indentation or switching to modern join syntax):

```
WITH t as (
     select CUSTOMER_ID,
    trunc(PURCHASE_DATE) dat,
    count(*) cnt
       from purchases
   group by CUSTOMER_ID, trunc(PURCHASE_DATE)
    )
    ,tt as (
        select t.*
        ,row_number() over (partition by CUSTOMER_ID order by dat) rn
        from t
    )
   ,ttt as (
   select CUSTOMER_ID, 
         min(dat) start_date,
         max(dat) end_date,
         count(*) day_count,
         sum(cnt) purchase_count
     from tt
     group by 
      CUSTOMER_ID, dat-rn
      having count(*) >= 10
   )
   select 
           c.customer_id,
           c.first_name,
           c.last_name,  
           ttt.start_date,
           ttt.end_date,
           ttt.day_count,
           ttt.purchase_count
     from   customers c, ttt
    where  
    c.customer_id = ttt.customer_id;
```

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE | DAY_COUNT | PURCHASE_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 14-APR-2023 00:00:00 | 24-APR-2023 00:00:00 | 11 | 11 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 02-MAR-2022 00:00:00 | 16-MAR-2022 00:00:00 | 15 | 15 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 22-APR-2023 00:00:00 | 14-MAY-2023 00:00:00 | 23 | 23 |
| 4 | Joseph | Zaza | 01-JAN-2023 00:00:00 | 13-JAN-2023 00:00:00 | 13 | 60 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AHfrUWW0)

I would recommend using a simpler approach though, as shown in @astentx's or @MTO's answers.

Comment: I'm going with MTO approach. I was just curious to see the final solution to what I had. Thanks for your expertise and response

Comment: @Pugzly I second you, it is one of those intriguing questions, isn't it =) MTO and Alex, I wonder if we could compare each of the execution plans for our solutions. I am quite eager to know the efficiency for these 160 or so records and for any exponents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT p.customer_id,
       c.first_name,
       c.last_name,
       TRUNC(p.first_purchase) AS first_day,
       TRUNC(p.last_purchase) - TRUNC(p.first_purchase) + 1 AS day_count,
       p.purchase_count
FROM   purchases
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY customer_id
         ORDER BY purchase_date
         MEASURES
           FIRST(purchase_date) AS first_purchase,
           LAST(purchase_date) AS last_purchase,
           COUNT(*) AS purchase_count
         PATTERN (consecutive_days+ final_day)
         DEFINE consecutive_days AS NEXT(purchase_date) < TRUNC(purchase_date) + INTERVAL '2' DAY
       ) p
       INNER JOIN customers c
       ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
WHERE  p.last_purchase >= TRUNC(p.first_purchase) + 9
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | FIRST_DAY | DAY_COUNT | PURCHASE_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Lisa | Saladino | 2023-04-14 00:00:00 | 11 | 11 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 2022-03-02 00:00:00 | 15 | 15 |
| 3 | Micheal | Palmice | 2023-04-22 00:00:00 | 23 | 23 |
| 4 | Joseph | Zaza | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 13 | 60 |

If you really want to do it using analytic functions and aggregation then the above query can be translated to:

```sql
WITH continuous as (
  SELECT customer_id,
         purchase_date,
         CASE
         WHEN purchase_date < TRUNC(LAG(purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY purchase_date)) + 2
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END AS is_not_continuous
  FROM   purchases p
),
groups as (
  SELECT customer_id,
         purchase_date,
         SUM(is_not_continuous) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY purchase_date)
          AS grp
 FROM   continuous c
),
totals AS (
  SELECT customer_id,
         TRUNC(MIN(purchase_date)) AS first_day,
         1 + TRUNC(MAX(purchase_date)) - TRUNC(MIN(purchase_date)) AS day_count,
         COUNT(*) AS purchase_count
  FROM   groups
  GROUP BY
         customer_id,
         grp
  HAVING 1 + TRUNC(MAX(purchase_date)) - TRUNC(MIN(purchase_date)) >= 10
)
SELECT c.customer_id,
       c.first_name,
       c.last_name,  
       t.first_day,
       t.day_count,
       t.purchase_count
FROM   customers c
       INNER JOIN totals t
       ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id;
```

Which has the same output.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nIZoEHDk)

Comment: @MTO what's the execution plan for your query?

Answer (score 1):

You may use mentioned `match_recognize` and define a match pattern as *has next purchase within a day after current row* repeated 9 times or more: the first row should match with no condition (as we have no rule for the start of the series) and then we need to have at least 9 rows with 1-day gap.

Below it the code on `purchases` table. This result may be joined to other tables to add labels etc to identifiers.

```
with distinct_days as (
  /*Group by day first to count entire days*/
  select
    customer_id,
    product_id,
    trunc(purchase_date) as purchase_date,
    sum(quantity) as quantity
  from purchases p
  group by 
    customer_id,
    product_id,
    trunc(purchase_date)
)
select *
from distinct_days
match_recognize (
  partition by customer_id
  order by purchase_Date asc
  measures
    first(purchase_Date) as first_date,
    last(purchase_Date) as last_Date,
    match_number() as grp,
    count(purchase_Date) as days_,
    sum(quantity) as quantity
--  all rows per match
  pattern(any_ next_day{9,})
  define
    next_day as trunc(purchase_Date) <= trunc(prev(purchase_Date)) + 1
)
order by customer_id, grp
```

| CUSTOMER_ID | FIRST_DATE | LAST_DATE | GRP | DAYS_ | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-04-24 | 1 | 11 | 22 |
| 3 | 2022-03-02 | 2022-03-16 | 1 | 15 | 15 |
| 3 | 2023-04-22 | 2023-05-14 | 2 | 23 | 23 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-13 | 1 | 13 | 60 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y6f5fBlv)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid using a match and produce the output in my post

Comment: I think they want `count(order_id)` not `sum(quantity)`... I did the same but that makes the first `purchase_count` 22 not 11.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way inspired by `DENSE_RANK()`

[dbFiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/cpTcDFO_)

```
    -- working 2
        
    with prank as
    (
      select dense_Rank() over (partition by customer_id 
      order by to_number(to_char(purchase_date, 'J'))) - 
      to_number(to_char(purchase_date, 'J')) as recRank, 
      purchase_date, customer_id 
      FROM purchases
    ), 
      prankdays as
    (select customer_id, trunc(max(purchase_date)) - 
               trunc(min(purchase_date)) + 1 as numRunningDays
      min(purchase_date), 
      max(purchase_date)        
    from prank
    group by customer_id, recRank
    having (extract(day from max(purchase_date) - min(purchase_date)) + 1) >=10
    )
    select c.first_name, c.last_name, p.*  
    from prankdays p, customers c 
    where p.customer_id = c.customer_id 
     
    
    -- notes:
    -- 1 extract(day from max(purchase_date) - min(purchase_date)) + 1
    --     doesn't include, therefore trunc is used where both start, end dates inclusive
    -- 2 count(*) records is not applied
    -- 3 dense rank works great for identifying gaps
    -- 4 there are two ways to get number of days between two dates here
    -- 5 a way to convert date to number is shown here
    -- I used the same dbfiddle table schema, data by @AlexPoole (cheers)
    ;
```

Output:

```
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   CUSTOMER_ID NUMRUNNINGDAYS  MIN(PURCHASE_DATE)          MAX(PURCHASE_DATE)
Lisa        Saladino    2           11              14-APR-23 01.00.00.000000   24-APR-23 11.00.00.000000
Micheal     Palmice     3           15              02-MAR-22 00.23.05.000000   16-MAR-22 05.46.15.000000
Micheal     Palmice     3           23              22-APR-23 23.00.00.000000   14-MAY-23 01.00.00.000000
Joseph      Zaza        4           13              01-JAN-23 05.00.00.000000   13-JAN-23 12.00.00.000000
```

Some food for thought:

> [Oracle
> documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DENSE_RANK.html)
>
> The [DENSE_RANK()](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-dense_rank/) is an analytic function in Oracle that calculates the rank of a
> row in an ordered set of rows. The returned rank is an integer
> starting from 1.
>
> Unlike the RANK() function, the DENSE_RANK() function returns rank
> values as consecutive integers. It does not skip rank in case of ties.
> Rows with the same values for the rank criteria will receive the same
> rank values.